# Data binding not working rivets js

Tags: rivets.js

I just started using rivets js a couple of days before. So i am studying it. But got stuck myself

I have created a fiddle here

What i want to do is. I want to remove the data from the div and put another set of data's inside that

So at first the binding is working. But second time when i empty the div and once again bind Its not working

Created Fiddle
http://fiddle.jshell.net/m8j4ycj1/

```
function render() {
    rivets.bind($("#hello"), datas);
     return this;
}

rivets.bind($("#hello"), data);

setTimeout(function(){
    debugger;
    $("#hello").empty();
    render();

},1000)
```

In this code the first binding is working but not after the setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you just want to empty the div?
so try to emtpy the model.

if data is:

```
data = { username: '12345' };
```

do

```
data.username = '';
```

and the view should be updated automatically

greez

Comment: it seems what Krishna is asking is more complicate : "I want to remove the data from the div and put another set of data's inside that"

Comment: some kind of "re-bind"? theres a ".update()" function on the binding-object where you can add a new model. but idk what happens with the old model (i think it will be replaced). otherwise just ".unbind()" and ".bind()" again.